# getting Syntax Error: Unexpected End of json input on deployment

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, syntax-error

I am trying to get users Ip address which works fine when running the code locally. But the problem arises when I deployed it in netlify.
Code samples:
Html:-

```
<body>
    <h1>Ip Address Tracker</h1>
    <div class="my-ip">
        <button class="myIp">Check My Ip</button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-ip">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search for any Ip" />
        <button>submit</button> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:-

```
let myIpBtn = document.querySelector('.myIp')
myIpBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json')
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.ip)
            getLocation(data.ip)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.message)
        })
})
```

I am getting Syntax Error: Unexpexted end of Json Input at line `.then(results => results.json())`

Source Code: https://github.com/Abir10101/test.git
app: https://abir10101.github.io/test/index.html

Comment: its mean results is not valid json format, try to debug it with `console.log(results)`

Comment: @RapSherlock the code is running fine locally in my pc. But I am getting the error after I deployed in netlify or github and running from the published link.

Comment: what you get from debug `results` ? its running fine on my console and SO snippet, so i don't know what result you get.

Comment: @RapSherlock `console.log(results)`- object of Response {type: "cors", ...}

Comment: @RapSherlock it is running fine locally.. showing error when i deployed it in github and running from the published link(not locally).

Comment: do it return error on fetch promise ? `object of Response {type: "cors", ...}` <- im not pretty sure from this results, but possibly your request is get blocked by cors

Comment: @RapSherlock yes it is returning promise. maybe the error by the cors

Comment: @RapSherlock Source Code: [link](https://github.com/Abir10101/test.git)
app: [link](https://abir10101.github.io/test/index.html)